# How to diagnose "Value of property Parameters must be an object with String (or simple type) properties"

Tags: aws-cloudformation

How do I diagnose which parameter(s) are causing my stack to fail with

`Value of property Parameters must be an object with String (or simple type) properties`

There are a couple of Q&As on here about passing lists in nested stacks, and maybe that's my problem (see below), but my more general question is, how do I determine which parameter is offensive?

---

I may end up asking this as a separate question, but just in case it helps with the above, I don't think I'm having a problem with passing lists, because I'm only using a few, and not passing them as lists. Template snippets:

Parent stack

```
AvailabilityZones:
  Type: List<AWS::EC2::AvailabilityZone::Name>
DNSZone:
  Type: List<AWS::Route53::HostedZone::Id>
OptionalPostfixConfig:
  Default: "4h,5d,300s,4000s,60s,50,3,20,25,3600"
  Type: CommaDelimitedList
ServerNames:
  Default: 'mx1.example.com,mx2.example.com,webmail.example.com'
  Type: CommaDelimitedList
```

Those are all of the lists in the parent stack. They are then passed thusly:

```
Properties:
  Parameters:
    AvailabilityZones: !Join [',', !Ref AvailabilityZones]
    DNSZone:
      !Ref DNSZone
    DelayWarningTime:
      !Select [0, !Ref OptionalPostfixConfig]
    PrimaryServerName:
      !Select [0, !Ref ServerNames]
```

DNSZone is of Type List, but only one item is ever selected to the list. So, maybe I'm wrong and something in the above doesn't work, but even if it doesn't, I'd still like to know how to figure out which.

Comment: !Join [',', !Ref DNSZone] is this work?

Comment: Thanks! That’s does fix at least that problem! However, if still like to know how to diagnose it. Isn’t there somewhere in the logs (or something that can be turned on) to get more detail on the error?

Comment: @philolegein I have the same question.  Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: I did not @Keven:(

Comment: There is a crude and simple, but also time-consuming way. Clumsy and takes time, but It does work.
 
If you comment out the parameters one by one, each time replacing each one with a simple string - this will fail the build later on, but as soon as you get past the error message, you know you've found the erroring parameter.